# Fixing header and print

Tags: sed, awk, perl

I have header starting with '>' and I want fix the header by keeping first word and removing other shown as in output.txt and print it

input.txt

```
>AGAJ01065549.1 scaffold:Xipmac4.4.2:AGAJ01065549.1:1:500:1 REF
CGCCAGGTGTCTGGCGTAATAGCGCCAGCGCCAGGTGTCATATACGTAATAGCGCCAGGT
>RGAMMT01065456.1 scaffold:Xipmac4.4.2:AGAJ01065595.1:1:500:1 REF
GACTAGTTTTTACATATAGTAATGGTTATTCGGAAGTGTACAGACGTTTTCAGGTTTTTT
TTTGGTAGGGGTTGAGGTGTTGAGGTGAGGGGACTATGTGGAGGGAACTTTCCATAGAGG
```

output.txt

```
>AGAJ01065549.1 
CGCCAGGTGTCTGGCGTAATAGCGCCAGCGCCAGGTGTCATATACGTAATAGCGCCAGGT
>RGAMMT01065456.1 
GACTAGTTTTTACATATAGTAATGGTTATTCGGAAGTGTACAGACGTTTTCAGGTTTTTT
TTTGGTAGGGGTTGAGGTGTTGAGGTGAGGGGACTATGTGGAGGGAACTTTCCATAGAGG
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/^>/s/\s.*//' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by piping the text through awk

```
awk '{print $1}' input.txt
```

This prints out the first entry of every line (entries are separated with spaces).

Comment: pass the file to awk directly, no need to cat and pipe it. Secondly your solution would break if non-header lines contain embedded spaces

Comment: True, but it addresses the example given and shows a solution that would work as long as the sample doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the [answer using `awk`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53676/606) is `cut`:

```
cut -d' ' -f 1 input.txt > output.txt
```

The `-d` option sets the delimiter to one space and `-f` selects the first field.

However you can also use `sed`:

```
sed 's,^\([^ ]\+\) .*,\1,' input.txt > output.txt
```

This command substitutes an expression. It looks the beginning of a line and copies every character into a buffer which is not white space. Furthermore it matches a white space and any other character. `sed` replaces this line with the buffer content.